# How is Flash able to communicate with his team?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash*, Flash is running at speeds greater than the speed of sound. Then how is he able to communicate live with his team (Cisco, Caitlin) while running? Since he is moving faster than sound it should not be possible to communicate live with his team. As we know when thunder happens light reaches first and then sound. There is a delay since sound travels slower than light.
How are Flash and his team communicating? Did I miss something?